# why initializer list cannot be main's parameter? how to propose it?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, program-entry-point, initializer-list

The valid C++ `main` signatures are the following:

```
int main()
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

But isn't allowed to declare `main` taking an initializer list:

```
int main(std::initializer_list<char *> args)
```

AFAIK the initializer list could be implemented as a pair of pointers or a pointer (this could be the `argv` parameter) plus a length (this could be deduced from the `argc` parameter), and its storage could be automatic, temporary, or static read-only memory [depending on the situation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

So i think that an `std::initializer_list<char *>` could handle and manage without any problem the command line parameters, then i'm wondering why this hypothetical `main` signature wasn't added after the approval of the initializer lists on the C++11 standard, and because of that i'm asking:

- What could be the disadvantages or problems derived of allowing an initializer list as the `main` only parameter? (i couldn't think of any).
- Which would be the correct way to propose to the standards committee this addition (or any other change)?

Comment: What would be the *advantage* of adding this? Features don't get added to C++ just because there are no disadvantages. You need to show that there are actual advantages.

Comment: technically your start function could be named anything, it is just a matter of telling the linker to use it as entry point e.g. `_tmain( int argc, wchar_t *argv[])`

Comment: Besides breaking all invocations of main - there is nothing but syntactical sugar to introduce that.

Comment: The second and third signatures are *exactly* the same. The standard does allow for other signatures as long as those two are accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there are two ways of specifying `main()` in a program, most (all?) current implementations of the C++ run-time call the `main()` function the same way (they pass the arguments as `(int, char *[])` irrespective to how `main()` is declared). Your proposal would require the C++ run-time of all implementations to figure out which kind of `main()` the program is using, and call the right `main()`. If you really want this functionality for yourself, you can always provide an implementation of `main(int, char *[])` that converts the arguments into an initializer list like object (such as `vector<>`), and then calls a new entry point function of your choice.

The process for submitting a proposal is described at the [Standard C++ website](http://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal). The basic steps are: (1) float the idea on their Usenet group/mailing list; (2) draft a proposal, solicit feedback, and update the proposal accordingly; and (3) repeat the process until the proposal is accepted.

Comment: I think his point was that you could implement `std::initializer_list` as a two-member struct and pass it by value to `main()` so that it would have the same stack layout as the two arguments (just two machine words) and that would not break binary compatibility (at least on x86).

Comment: @szx: That would impose a requirement on the layout of `std::initializer_list` instead of leaving it up to the implementation. When I read the documentation for `std::initializer_list` it seems more like an `array<>` or a `vector<>`, neither of which requires an extra word to specify the size.

Comment: As the question says, there are already two standard forms for `main`: `int main()` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, but they are called the same way (the arguments are passed whether you specify them in the function prototype or not). I admit, the standard does not specify that an implementation is required to do it that way, though.

Comment: @jxh: Perhaps on some implementations; perhaps even on all existing implementations. But I see nothing in the standard that says they're called the same way. If the invocation of `main` is an ordinary function call, then the two forms are incompatible, and calling `main` with two arguments when it expects none would have undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I am just describing the barrier. I did not say "don't bother trying to propose it". I even took the effort to describe how to propose it.

Comment: @jxh: Understood. I'm quibbling about a relatively minor detail: there are already two standard ways to define `main`, and implementations already have to deal with that somehow. I'm not defending the proposal; in fact, IMHO it's not worth proposing.

Comment: "irregardless" isn't a word.

Comment: @0x499602D2: [Irregardless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irregardless) **is** a word.

Comment: @jxh Do you want to take this to english.stackexchange! :) Just joking

Comment: @0x499602D2: You gain the ability to edit posts without approval at 2000 points. You have over 22,000 points, so no, it's not recent.

Comment: Thanks for describing the proposal process and provide a link, however my first question wasn't completely answered, but your answer is the most complete and neat one. It would be nice if your edit your answer to add texts from the standard that explains the points you answered.

Comment: @jxh, `std::array` knows its size, it's a compile-time constant, and `std::vector` use _three_ words, pointing to the first element, past the last element and past the end of allocated storage. A typical `std::initializer_list` implementation is a pair of pointers.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Oh, right, I forgot vector tracks its capacity as well as its size.

Answer (score 4):

It is worth noting that a library (but not the standard C++ library according to 3.6.1 [basic.start.main] paragraph 2, first sentence: "An implementation shall not predefine the `main` function.") could just define function `main()` and implement it in a suitable way, e.g., calling `app_main()`:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
extern int app_main(std::vector<std::string> const&);

int main(int ac, char* av[]) {
    return app_main(std::vector<std::string>(av, av + ac));
}
```

Since `main()` can't be overloaded (according to 3.6.1 [basic.start.main] paragraph 2, second sentence: "This function shall not be overloaded.") the entry point needs a different name. Since `std::initializer_list<T>` cannot be constructed other than using `{ ... }`, a different type than `std::initializer_list<T>` needs to be used. While being at it, the above implementation also chooses to turn the `char*` into `std::string` objects.

To use the above function, an application would just implement `app_main()` and it would get called:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

int app_main(std::vector<std::string> const& args) {
    std::cout << "received the arguments: ";
    std::copy(args.begin(), args.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; // return statement can't be omitted, of course
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to the considerations of the C compatibility and not the technical reasons. There are a lot stuff inherited from C.

Comment: Just because they inherited that from C doesn't mean they can't add another one, lots of stuff in C++ is not compatible with C