# Define main function in class

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, friend

I was wondering if its possible to define `main()` inside a class, something like:

```
struct runtime_entry_point
{
    friend int main()
    {

    }
};
```

I have tested that and it doesn't work (Almost in GCC 4.8.2):

> g++     -o dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/turbo build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o 
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib/crt1.o: 
>   In function `_start': collect2: error: ld exited with status 1

*This sounds to me like a no definition of `main()` error*.

Later, I have written main in the classic way:

```
struct runtime_entry_point
{
    friend int main()
    {

    }
};

int main(){}
```

Now the compilation fails because `int main()` was already defined inside the struct `runtime_entry_point`! **Whats happening here?**

Comment: Whatever you're doing: don't do it.

Comment: @MilesRout I was just out of curiosity. But if you wan't to kow the context, I'm doing template metaprogramming, I'm searching a way to automatice the generation of `main()`, which commonly does nothing in tmp metaprograms.

Comment: Note for all people: I'm not asking if definning `main()` in a struct is a good practice or not, I'm asking about the reason of the above situation (`main()` is not defined vs previous definition inside the struct)

Comment: There's a way, immigrate to Java.

Comment: You can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23553723/2567683) yesterday's discussion  on templatizing `main`, that made it to isocpp's selected recent questions. If you read through the comments of Jefffrey's answer there a thorough explanation of the c++ intrinsic's related to main. But I suppose you're already aware of the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аccording to the [article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) on cppreference.com, the following construction:

```
struct runtime_entry_point
{
    friend int main()
    {
    }
};
```

Defines a non-member function, and makes it a friend of this class at the same time. Such non-member function is always inline.

Linker couldn't find main() in object file (inline function), and you can't declare another main() in the same translation unit (as it already declared).

Answer (score 4):

Trivially it is not possible to write `main` as a part of a class/struct. The linker by default searches for a free `main` method and links against it, makes it the entry point. You *may* alter this behavior by at the linker level, in which case `main` must be a **static** method in class/struct. But this is linker implementation dependent, not-portable and dangerous.

However, in the second situation you mentioned is a result of violation of [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). You are defining a name (`main()`) more than once in a single translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

You can not **define** a function twice, it works when you change the definition into a declaration inside the class/struct:

```
#include <iostream>

struct runtime_entry_point
{
    friend int main();
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

This works [just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11ba36a4546bb8b9) with GCC.